# ID3 Decision Tree Clarification

Tags: java, decision-tree

I am currently working on implementing an ID3 algorithm. I've been going through the classic play tennis example, however I cannot seem to understand why the attribute TEMPERATURE is left out of the final tree. Could anyone explain why this is so?

**DATA SET**
[image]

**FINAL DECISION TREE**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ID3 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm#Algorithm) finishes in one of three scenarios:

- every element in the subset belongs to the same class (+ or -), then the node is turned into a leaf and labelled with the class of the examples
- there are no more attributes to be selected, but the examples still do not belong to the same class (some are + and some are -), then the node is turned into a leaf and labelled with the most common class of the examples in the subset
- there are no examples in the subset, this happens when no example in the parent set was found to be matching a specific value of the selected attribute, for example if there was no example with age >= 100. Then a leaf is created, and labelled with the most common class of the examples in the parent set.

Take, for example Outlook: sunny and Humidity: high/normal. There are three "high" rows, and they all say No to tennis. Therefore, the first scenario occurs, and leaves can be created. There is more information, but it's not needed in order to make a decision.

Answer (score 0):

**How does the creation of the ID3 tree work?**

The first thing you have to do is take out the information gain of each attribute. But there is a rule that maybe you are jumping and it is:
- The analysis of the number of positives and negatives. If all records with that attribute as a result have only positive or negative. You do not need to ask anymore.

Knowing this rule explains why in the case of temperature I did not keep adding ramifications.

But if there are positive and negative results when counting the rows, you will need to ask another question, for example, you will review all possible combinations such as sunny with Overcast or Rain and the one with the highest information gain will be placed as a child of that branch.

That procedure will do so until you find that all rows have only negative or positive. When it passes then it will define as a sheet the result.

Also, it is important to mention that the tree will grow depending on the number of rows that your data set has.

I implemented the ID3 in javascript, I leave the repository where it is hosted. https://github.com/Danils123/Id3Algoritmo.git